# How to create simple Venn Diagram

Tags: r

I need to know how to create a simple Venn diagram in rstudio.  I have the following data: A=25, B=19, A&B=7

I have no idea wear to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn_plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(area1=25,
                                area2=19,
                                cross.area=7,
                                category=c('A', 'B'),
                                scaled=FALSE)
```

Source: http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/GraphicalTools/Venn.html

[image: Image of Venn diagram]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add a third data circle 'C', with this code? Or is the max number of circles two?

Comment: Have a look at the `draw.triple.venn` function in the `VennDiagram` library.

Comment: Thanks. I have been playing around with draw.triple.venn and draw.quad.venn. I've created a graph to my liking. The one thing I need to change is the font of the labels to arial. Any idea how I would go about doing this?